# Sql select union with count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which returns rows with a bunch of unions. What I am trying to do is see if the select statement does not yield any rows, and if so, execute another script.

This is the current sql select I am using in the stored procedure. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

```
SELECT  name AS [Name],  address1 AS Address1, address2 AS Address2, city AS City,  1 AS DeliveryTypeKey, email AS Email,  
  ( SELECT TOP 1   c_phone_number   
    FROM phone WITH (NOLOCK)  
    WHERE value = @value) AS Fax 
    FROM #Cities x    
 INNER JOIN prov p WITH (NOLOCK) ON x.ckey = p.pkey  
 UNION 
SELECT  name AS [Name], address1 AS Address1, address2 AS Address2, city AS City,  1 AS DeliveryTypeKey, email AS Email,  
  ( SELECT TOP 1 c_phone_number   
    FROM phone WITH (NOLOCK)  
    WHERE value = @value) AS Fax 
    FROM #Cities1 x    
    INNER JOIN prov1 p WITH (NOLOCK) ON x.ckey = p.pkey  
 UNION 
 SELECT  name AS [Name], address1 AS Address1, address2 AS Address2, city AS City,  1 AS DeliveryTypeKey, email AS Email,  
  ( SELECT TOP 1 c_phone_number   
    FROM phone WITH (NOLOCK)  
    WHERE value = @value) AS Fax 
 FROM #Cities2 x    
 INNER JOIN prov2 p WITH (NOLOCK) ON x.ckey = p.pkey
```

Comment: Why can't you just wrap it in a subquery returning the count?

Comment: As i have around 20 unions in the query, subquery to get actual count and with actual query it becomes a huge stored proc. I was trying to see any better options than this if not i will go with subquery approach.

Comment: What is the difference between the #Cities, #Cities1 etc. tables? Could they be merged to eliminate the UNIONs?

Comment: I think you should do this check from code (or from where ever you runt the SP) and if the result is empty run the other script.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ROWCOUNT function to check if any rows where returned:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
  ( 
     DATA INT 
  ) 

INSERT @table 
VALUES (0) 

SELECT * 
FROM   @table 
WHERE  DATA > 0 

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
  SELECT 'run' 
ELSE 
  SELECT 'Don''t run'
```